# CPU utilization calculation in Amdahl's law

Tags: java, concurrency, parallelism-amdahl

I am reading "Java Concurrency In Practice" and am stuck at one calculation presented in Amdahl's law section. Full text is also available here:  https://flylib.com/books/en/2.558.1/amdahls_law.html

" With ten processors, a program with 10% serialization can achieve at most a speedup of 5.3 **(at 53% utilization**), and with 100 processors it can achieve at most a speedup of 9.2 (**at 9% utilization**). It takes a lot of inefficiently utilized CPUs to never get to that factor of ten."

I understand the speedup calculation but how is the CPU utilization came to be 53% in first case and 9% in 2nd case?

Comment: Which calculation(s) do you not understand?  Where the `5.3` speedup comes from, or where the `53%` utilisation ratio comes from?  Do some more research on SO, perhaps start reading at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812808/understanding-amdahls-law

Comment: As I have clearly mentioned that my question was about CPU utilization and not speedup. This is not covered in the StackOverflow question you have mentioned.